# Superuser in xmpp (for a pubsub service)

Tags: xmpp

Is there a kind of a superuser or admin for a pubsub service who can literally do everything for example a useful pubsub nodes use-case:

- Delete a collection or a leaf node which has been created by another entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be implementation specific, so it would have to be set in your server (providing your server supports such a user).

For example, in Openfire you would set the property

```
xmpp.pubsub.sysadmin.jid
```